# How to enable scrollable feature in Date/Time picker in Android?

Tags: android, scroll, datetimepicker, android-timepicker

As shown in this  [IMAGE](http://s15.postimg.org/53khf165n/pickers.png), once the Time/Date picker dialog opens, I can vary individual value by tapping + or -, but **scrolling is almost not possible**, with great difficulty I can scroll only to one value higher or lower. But I am not able to get ***smooth scrollability feature***.

How can I make android Time/Date picker scrollable ?

Can someone tell me what correction can I do ?

Comment: Scrolling is enabled by default. Are you sure this is the type of picker you're seeing as shown in the screen shot?

Comment: @JoelFernandes Yes I am sure

Comment: Where are the + and - buttons?

Comment: @JoelFernandes What I mean is + -> Upper Arrow & - -> Lower Arrow